# Has this question on Absolute Value's been asked wrong?

Tags: absolute-value

I was going over some basics on Khan's Academy in preparation for a test. To my surprise I got this wrong:

[image]

Has this been worded wrong? Surely the person farthest from sea level is Howard?

This question was asked in the the context of Absolute Values. But the question didn't specifically ask the reader to take the absolute values.

Had I have taken the absolute value, then question one would have been wrong because the greatest absolute value would have been Peter.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: "Farthest from" automatically implies absolute value; greatest elevation is direct value comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers are correct. The elevation of Howard is of course greater than elevation of Peter. I know, what is your problem.

When we say that a person gained $20rs$ today we write it in the profit box as $20rs$ and when he loses $20rs$ so the entry would be like this (in the profit box): $-20rs$.

If some one asks the person that what is the relation between lost and profit. He would say that they are equal but if someone ask that on which day you got bigger profit, he will absolutely say, "the first one was bigger".

> In your case, *depression* of Peter from sea level is greater than *elevation* of Howard from sea level but, elevation of Howard is greater than elevation of Peter.

Do it by imposing a coordinate system on the relevant picture and you will get it easily.

Comment: I have made the most stupidest of blunders. I assumed sea level was at the base of the sea floor. Which is probably even more ridiculous. I see now the question is infact correct.